# Custom iOS video recording UI

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

How can I implement a custom video recording screen with my own buttons?
Below you can find how it is implemented at this moment.

```
@IBAction func RecordAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        print("Camera Available")
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
    else {
        print("Camera Unavailable")
    }

}
```

Comment: Too broad. What buttons do you want? Where are they? Do you intend to keep using the image picker? If so, why is `showsCameraControls` true? If not, why show this code at all? It is far from clear what you want or what research you've done.

Comment: I showed the code that I'm using at this moment. What I would like to do is to have a back button image showing a back arrow, a count down when recording starts, going from 5 to 1, then recording starts. Basically adding custom image buttons on top of the recording view

Comment: So put the button in the `cameraOverlayView` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619113-cameraoverlayview) and write the code for it.